# Symfony: add foreign keys programmatically

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a pretty bad database structure to work with, that doesn't have foreign keys relationships declared in itself, and I have to use this database as the model with Symfony.

For some reasons, I cannot alter this database, have to work with it as it is. Also, don't want to edit YML files.

How can I declare foreign keys directly in the symfony's php classes? Prefferably classes that won't be overwriten if I regenerate the model.

Searched for this but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: What are you using? Doctrine? Propel?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine.

I found the answer here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en

Have to override the BaseClass's setUp() method with hasMany or hasOne relations.

Comment: That class would be overwritten if you regenerate the model

Comment: Yeah, of course. By overriding setUp() I didn't mean editing the BaseClass's file, but overriding it in the Class that extends BaseClass (one level up in the file directory). Thanks.